# Getting connection property name

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

The following script here has a hardcoded name of a connection (TD_NAME). i would like to make this a variable that fetches the connection name as it is in the server.

```
write-host "Connections folder > TD_NAME > "
```

for example, in the image, the variable would grab the "Teradata DEV" name and pass it in the output message.

[image: connection_name]

This is what i am trying to implement:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$as = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$as.connect("$Server")  

$c = $as.Databases | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $Database } #this gets the CUBE to get its relevant connection property

### Here goes whatever the code is that will expand the connection folder (if necessary) and get the connection name ###
#Example: 
# $TD_NAME = c.connectionsomething...

write-host "Processing job failed!`r`nCheck the TD credentials by expanding the CUBE Connections folder > $TD_NAME > Properties > Connection String"
```

Comment: This is familiar. Did you delete the previous question and ask it again? FYI that is how you would get a question ban.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the script that you need help with. Currently, all this shows is a `write-host`

Comment: @jrider added what im trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataSources` property of the AS Database oject

```
$c.DataSources.Name
$c.DataSources.ConnectionString
```

Comment: nice! btw, for the connection string, it only displays user ID and server. is it possible to get the password property as well to change it?

Comment: Depending on the [ConnectionStringSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.connectionstringsecurity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2016) Property the password is automatically removed for security reasons… The ConnectionString can be set...

Comment: So it's impossible to be able to change the password through script?

Comment: No… the password is removed by reading the property… you should be able to set the ConnectionString to whatever you like.

Comment: can you emphasize what you mean by "setting the connection string?" do you mean setting it to get the password? i am kinda confused...

Comment: It should be possible to do $c.DataSources[0].ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog....;User Id=…;Password=…."